# calculadora simples, mas retornando sempre o valor "C"

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Nesse projeto de calculadora, eu me deparei com um problema, quando eu clico em qualquer que seja o botão, ele simplesmente me retorna a tecla "C", queria uma resposta do porque que sempre retorna "C" envés de retornar o texto da tecla que foi pressionada, a pergunta é porque sempre volta "C"*

`Pyside6`

> *aqui é usado buttonslot para adiar a execução da inserção do texto do botão dentro do qline.*

```
def _makeGrid(self):
        for rowNumber, rowData in enumerate(self._gridMask):
            for colNumber, buttonText in enumerate(rowData):
                button = Button(buttonText)
                self.addWidget(button, rowNumber, colNumber)
                buttonSlot = self._makeButtonDisplaySlot(
                    self._insertButtonTextToDisplay,
                    button,
                )
                button.clicked.connect(buttonSlot)
```

> *Aqui entra o problema, pois quando eu mando dar print dentro _makeBUttonDisplaySlot e fora do escopo de realslot, ele imprime todos os textos dos botões, oque está correto, mas quando entro com um print dentro do escopo de realslot, imprime só a letra "C".

```
def _makeButtonDisplaySlot(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
     @Slot(bool)
     def realSlot(_):
         func(*args, **kwargs)
     return realSlot
```

foto do que acontece quando clico qualquer coisa sem ser "C"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeLqV.png

Comment: Para prosseguir dentro do objetivo do site é importante [restaurar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/583597/70) e editar conforme orientado lá. Para evitar duplicação de conteúdo, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na outra postagem se restaurada.